# How distinguish between multicore and multiprocessor systems?

Tags: cpu

[This is](http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/results/res2013q2/) a list with performance of some CPU's on a benchmark data.
I cannot understand how to distinguish between multicore systems from multiprocessors ones. Do multicore systems have more than one enabled chip (second subcolumn in processor column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multicore means more than one core.

A single computer (motherboard) can have more than one CPU.

A single CPU can have more than 1 core.

Some cores are physical and others are virtual. The virtual ones perform ~-5%/+20% of a real one. Sometimes people disable virtual cores.

The following is an image of a CPU chip
[image: http://images.anandtech.com/reviews/cpu/intel/lynnfield/review/LFDDieLayout.jpg]

The following entry:

Acer Incorporated   Altos R380 F2 (Intel Xeon E5-2603)

8 cores

2 CPU chips with 4 cores on each chip

Each core ran 1 thread

Comment: if a core has 1 thread, does it mean that there is no pipleining?

Comment: @msh Pipleining is transparent to a program and consumer. It is wholly unrelated.

Comment: If a system has two chips, does it meant that it is multiprocessor?

Comment: Is 2CPU chip considered multiprocessro or not? I am just trying figureout terminology.

Comment: @capoluca It can mean multiprocessor, but generally not. Especially since multi-core processors have come out. When AMD released the first dual core it became pretty important to distinguish between multiprocessor and multicore.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mikhail pointed out:

Each Motherboard can have 1 or more processors(each processor takes one physical socket).

Each processor can have 1 or more cores(cores are internal to a processor and are not visible to the naked eye).

- A single Processor, single core processor, would have 1 core.
- A single Processor, dual core processor, would have 2 cores.
- A dual Processor, single core processors, would have 2 cores.
- A dual Processor, dual core processors, would have 4 cores.
- A quad processor, quad core processors, would have 16 cores.

Referencing one of the PDF(s) on that page:

http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/results/res2013q2/cpu2006-20130322-25600.pdf

From the "platform notes":

```
From /proc/cpuinfo
 model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 0 @ 1.80GHz
 2 "physical id"s (chips)
 8 "processors"
 cores, siblings (Caution: counting these is hw and system dependent. The
 following excerpts from /proc/cpuinfo might not be reliable. Use with
 caution.)
 cpu cores : 4
 siblings : 4
 physical 0: cores 0 1 2 3
 physical 1: cores 0 1 2 3
```

This implies that:

- there were 2 physical processors(2 sockets on the motherboard, with 1 processor chip in each socket).
- There were 4 cores per processor, giving a total of 8 "processors".

Depending on the operating system, some OS(s) don't differentiate between "cpus" and "cores" and just calls them all "processors", which can be confusing. However, the output in that document is clear: 4 cores per physical cpu chip, giving you 8 cores.

Hope that helps in interpreting the information in those docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell out the tables from that page, because the two existing answers are already dead on and excellent answers:

[image]

Enabled Cores is total cores (Physical processors + Physical Cores)

Enabled Chips is Physical Processors.

Cores / Chip is exactly that, how many physical cores per physical processor. Cores * Chips should add up to enabled cores. (2 Processors at 4 cores per processor = 8). Threads per core is essentially is hyper threading enabled (HTT). So for the 2690 Listed below Windows would see 2 processors at 8 cores per chip with Hyperthreading enabled and report you have 32 processors, these are logical processors. You have 2 * 8 physical cores, or 16 cores.